# Hola tengo un problema con una consulta en Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 2 consultas de una misma tabla que son las siguientes:

```
SELECT start as fecha, COUNT(*) as totaldia FROM incidences WHERE active = 0 GROUP BY start
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT start as fecha, COUNT(*) as totaldia FROM incidences GROUP BY start
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podría unir ambas consultas para poder obtener la fecha y la multiplicación del totaldia como la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que tengo que realizar un select dentro de otro select pero no he podido resolver esa parte.
De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si te entendi bien, pero creo que lo que buscas es contar todas las fechas para totalizarlas y en otra columna contar aquellas que tengan `active = 0`, podrías lograrlo así:

```
SELECT 
start as fecha,
COUNT(IF(active = 0,1,NULL)) as 'active=0',
COUNT(start) as total 
FROM incidences
GROUP BY start;
```

Te dejo un ejemplo: <kbd>[Ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a722b9a2842342822f4c1eaf5de06d4)</kbd>

Comment: Si, eso era lo que buscaba. Gracias!!!

Comment: @WillAz si la respuesta te fue de utilidad considera darle un +1 y/o marcarla como aceptada